# Using a "to-infinitive" after coordinating conjunctions (e.g., "and") or not?

Tags: infinitives, coordinating-conjunctions

I am wondering whether the "to" should be repeated after a coordinating conjunction or not. For example,

a) [...] practical examples to round up the learning experience and provide the tools for real-world applications.

b) [...] practical examples to round up the learning experience and **to** provide the tools for real-world applications.

Are both a) or b) correct? If yes, which one is to be preferred in terms of "good style"?

Comment: Both are equally grammatical, and I can think of no stylistic difference, either. Repeating the _to_ **may** in some circumstances sound a tad old-fashioned or a bit more formal, but in general I’d say there’s no difference between the two. Do note, however, that _example_ is more commonly used with _of_ + gerund than _to_ + infinitive. Of course, since we can’t see the rest of your sentence, the infinitive may make sense in context here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Janus. I am not a native English speaker, but I agree with you, the of + gerund sounds more natural. In this context, I didn't use a complete sentence, but used this phrase an keyword item in a numbered list, i.e.,   "I had 3 big goals in mind: 1. ..., 2. ..., 3. Providing practical examples to round up the learning experience and provide the tools for real-world applications." I used the infinitive to avoid 2 gerunds.

Comment: It depends on what it’s supposed to mean: does it refer to examples that show how to round up the learning experience, or does it refer to providing practical examples in order to round up the learning experience? If it’s the latter, then the infinitive is fine; if it’s the former, a gerund is miles better.

Comment: In a formal written piece of work I think I would repeat the *to* and go for your second example. But not everyone would agree with me and it would not constitute an error to drop it.

Comment: The difference between the two examples relates to the relationship between the two results. If I say, "practical examples to round up the learning experience and provide the tools for real-world applications," I am suggesting that rounding up the learning experience and providing the tools are quite closely related, as in "to round up the learning experience, which in turn provides the tools." If I add the second "to," I am making it clear that either result could stand alone and that there is no relationship between the two.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's the second. It refers to content that is rich in mathematical equations and machine learning theory. The "practical" examples are supposed to help understand the material but also provide something that the reader can use in a real world application. This, may sound a little bit weird without the complete context, the "practical examples" are referring to data visualization and code in a machine learning book

Comment: @surlawda thanks for the nice explanation, it makes absolute sense. Although I posted a particular example, I was really interested in the general "recommendation," and I will keep your suggestion in mind when I write a similar sentences in future. Thanks.

Comment: @surlawda I am quite new to "english.stackexchange" and don't know the etiquette very well, yet, but maybe you could post your comment as an answer below so that we could close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both (a) and (b) are correct.  (a) is better (swifter) if the context is clear, but (b) is better is there is any ambiguity: a long or nested phrase before the conjunction, a verb (instead of 'provide') that might be mistaken for a noun or adj (such as 'package'), or simply a complex idea that is new to a student.